# Applying the attributes of polygons to a line segment

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, polygon, overlapping-features

I am trying to classify a line segment (pipeline) based off of surrounding features. I have created polygons that contain the necessary attributes (count of  total nearby houses) that overlap this line segment.

I want to apply the count of these overlapping polygons to the line segment.

Answer (score 1):

Attempt doing a spatial join between your line segments and the polygons. This should join the polygons features to the lines